# AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'get' with Flask, GraphQL, and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, graphql

I am currently working on a Flask application that uses GraphQL (Graphene) for API operations and SQLAlchemy for ORM. I am encountering an issue when trying to retrieve all users from my database using a GraphQL query.

*Note: My models are auto-generated using automap_base since I created my DB schema with DataGrip*

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    users = graphene.List(UserObject)

    def resolve_users(self, info):
        print("Resolving users...")
        query = UserObject.get_query(info)
        return query.all()
```

When I attempt to execute a GraphQL query to fetch all users, I am presented with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The traceback points to the following lines in my code:

```
query = UserObject.get_query(info)
```

I am a bit stumped about why I'm encountering this issue. My understanding is that info.context in Graphene should contain the request object from Flask, and I am unsure why it does not have the 'get' attribute. My mutations work fine, but my queries do not

Could someone guide me on how to correctly set up my GraphQL context or resolve this error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my app.py for complete reference: https://pastebin.com/CV78xhPK

Answer (score 0):

So after some trial and error, I figured it out. The issue was that my flask-graphene application did not have a session attribute.

You need to inject the SQLAlchemy session into the context of your GraphQL execution. You can accomplish this by modifying the creation of your GraphQLView in your flask server file file.

You can make your db session globally scoped by importing g from flask

```
from flask import Flask, g
```

Then you need to add a before request method to fire once a request has been made, assigning the db session to a global variable

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = db.session
```

Then you can edit your GraphQL endpoint

```
app.add_url_rule(
    "/graphql",
    view_func=GraphQLView.as_view(
        "graphql",
        schema=schema,
        graphiql=True,
        get_context=lambda: {'session': g.db}  # Add this line
    )
```

)